# No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu>=1.16.0 when installing Pyannote from GitHub

Tags: macos, github, pip, conda, onnxruntime

I need to install Pyannote-audio for a project and its requirements (requirements.txt) include onnxruntime-gpu v1.16.0 or higher but I can't install it. GitHub link to the package: https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio

I read somewhere that onnxruntime (not onnxruntime-gpu) works on Python<3.10 so I installed pyenv to switch to 3.9 but changing the version did not make a difference. I tried installing it with pip, pip3 and conda. Conda only had onnxruntime, NOT onnxruntime-**gpu**. I can install onnxruntime, but Pyannote won't work without onnxruntime-**gpu**.

onnxruntime-gpu install attempt

```
(Health) positive@Positives-MacBook-Air Health_Project % python --version                                          
Python 3.9.18
(Health) positive@Positives-MacBook-Air Health_Project % pip install onnxruntime-gpu==1.16.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-gpu==1.16.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu==1.16.0
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Pyannote install attempt

```
(Health) positive@Positives-MacBook-Air Health_Project % pip install git+https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio

Collecting git+https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio
  Cloning https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio to /private/var/folders/9s/qklpxqb97t7cvv5cz01vb27h0000gn/T/pip-req-build-rfg6qf22
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio /private/var/folders/9s/qklpxqb97t7cvv5cz01vb27h0000gn/T/pip-req-build-rfg6qf22
  Resolved https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio to commit 26ca0514394ee8faef044b1da0fcf99e53cc22c1
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting asteroid-filterbanks>=0.4 (from pyannote.audio==3.0.1)
  Using cached asteroid_filterbanks-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting einops>=0.6.0 (from pyannote.audio==3.0.1)
  Using cached einops-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting huggingface-hub>=0.13.0 (from pyannote.audio==3.0.1)
  Using cached huggingface_hub-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting lightning>=2.0.1 (from pyannote.audio==3.0.1)
  Using cached lightning-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (64 kB)
Collecting omegaconf<3.0,>=2.1 (from pyannote.audio==3.0.1)
  Using cached omegaconf-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyannote-audio to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-gpu>=1.16.0 (from pyannote-audio) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu>=1.16.0
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

macOS Ventura v13.5

Python v3.9.18

pip v23.3

conda v23.5.2

Comment: At https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime-gpu/1.16.0/#files there're wheels foe Linux and w64, not for MacOS. At https://onnxruntime.ai/index.html#getStartedTable if you choose Mac and Python the only supported variant is "Default CPU". The bottom line: `onnxruntime` doesn't support GPU acceleration on Mac. Either use CPU wheels for MacOS from https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/1.16.0/#files or change your platform.

Comment: Thanks, the platform is likely the cause as you mentioned. For now, I found that working on Google's colab solves the issue temporarily. I will try changing platforms later in the timeline of our project.